# Compiling Bzip2 with C++11

Tags: c++11, cmake, bzip2, makefile

I'm trying to compile the [MultiBoost Library](http://www.multiboost.org/download) with C++11 but I can't make it work. The problem seems to be with the BZip2 Library that is used internally. More specificly there is a wrapper called Bzip2Wrapper to provide a c++ interface to the C library. All the files of the C library are included in the same folder. When using the default make file everything works but when I change

```
project(multiboost)
```

to

```
project(multiboost CXX)
```

I get the following errors:

```
libMultiBoostLib.a(Serialization.cpp.o): In function     `Bzip2WrapperReader::open(char const*)':
Serialization.cpp:(.text._ZN18Bzip2WrapperReader4openEPKc[_ZN18Bzip2WrapperReader4openEPKc]+0x97): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzReadOpen'
Serialization.cpp:(.text._ZN18Bzip2WrapperReader4openEPKc[_ZN18Bzip2WrapperReader4openEPKc]+0xc5): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzReadClose'
libMultiBoostLib.a(Serialization.cpp.o): In function `Bzip2WrapperReader::close()': ...
```

The CMakeList file looks like this

```
# Bzip2
file(GLOB bzip2_SRCS "${BASEPATH}/Bzip2/*.cpp" "${BASEPATH}/Bzip2/*.c" "${BASEPATH}/Bzip2/*.h")
add_library(Bzip2Lib STATIC ${bzip2_SRCS})
#add_library(bzip2 SHARED ${bzip2_lib_SRCS})
...    
# adding library to the exec
target_link_libraries(multiboost MultiBoostLib Bzip2Lib)
```

Any ideas what could go wrong? I don't even know what the problem is.
Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like any makefile I have ever seen.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It seems that the project is using CMake, which is a meta build system commonly used these days.

Comment: Yes, I meant the CMakeList file, will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a C++11 error but an error in the Build system.

I have not looked at the Code, but from the output you added something like this

`target_link_libraries(MultiBoostLib PUBLIC Bzip2Lib)`

should add the missing dependency from libMultiBoostLib on libBzip2Lib.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was adding "CXX" to my project description which disabled the use of C. Therefore the libraries (in C) could not be compiled. Changing it to "project(name C CXX)" solved this issue. I then also needed to include the line "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")" to enable C++11 support. Now everything is working.

Thanks a lot!